# Events firing at wrong time (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have a basic problem that I have tried but been unable to fix. I have 2 different values so the player can have 2 equipped pets in my game, but the problem is that when the first one changes the second one also fires because it meets the requirements of the if statement. I just need a way to stop the script until the player does an action in that script or just a different way to handle the situation. Here is my script that is causing the issue.

```
            if player.EquippedPets.Value == 0 then
                player.EquippedPets.Value += 1
                game.ReplicatedStorage.EquipPet:FireServer(pet.Name)
                end
                
                if player.EquippedPets.Value == 1 then
                player.Pet2Equipped.Value += 1
                game.ReplicatedStorage.EquipPet2:FireServer(pet.Name)
            end
```

The fire server works fine, it is just the part where it says "if player.EquippedPets.Value = "   " All I need is a way to stop the second one firing as soon as the first one does. I have tried disabling and enabling the script but then the other parts of the script don't work when I want them to. Any help appreciated!

Comment: What's about an `elseif`?

Comment: No way... It worked! Thanks a lot. Now I can keep working on my game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change it to an ‘elseif’.